# How do I add a managed property for a column on a list when I do not see a crawled property to map to?

Tags: search, managed-property, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm working with SharePoint 2013 Enterprise. I've taken over the management of another SharePoint setup created by the person that had my job before me. I want to be able to query against the search api against a specific column, Alternate Name, for which I do not see any managed or crawled property created. I know the column is not a site column. That said, SharePoint shows that it has an internal name of `"Alternate_x0020_Name"`. I've done both an incremental and full crawl after ensuring that numerous list items have an Alternate Name value. I have searched both managed & crawled properties via the Search Schema on nearly every variation of `"Alternate_x0020_Name"` I can think of, including searching on each singular part of the column name. Best I can see is that there simply isn't one. That said, if I try creating a new managed property and mapping it to a crawled property...well I could, but I do not see a field to map to.

The api I'm querying against follows a URL signature like:

```
http://sharepoint_server/_api/search/query?querytext='alt name value'&rowlimit=500
```

There are A LOT of columns that this particular api does not return as part of it's xml, though, I haven't figured out how to add more columns even by adding the `&SelectedProperties='properties here'`.

I've reviewed a number of links, but am still not sure what to make of my scenario. It doesn't seem like a managed property was auto-created and it doesn't seem like there's anything to map it to if I create a new one.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

The links I've reviewed are below. I've also gone further into these by following and reading subsequent links that were posted as part of various answers.

[List Column as Crawled Property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111255/list-column-as-crawled-property?rq=1)

[How to check correct Crawled property for a list column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158199/how-to-check-correct-crawled-property-for-a-list-column)

https://johnrossjr.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/creating-custom-managed-properties/

Answer (score 0):

i think, you did not enable search for the list, first enable the search for list then run the crawler.then it will generate the crawler property so you can map it with managed property. refer the screen

[image]

Comment: Actually, search is enabled. I can search on title and description and a few others thing. But, that said, the "Alternate_x0020_Name" is not the only column on the list that is not searchable (or doesn't seem to have a default value returned) via the http://sharepoint_server/_api/search/ api.